# Can I use Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0 on an embedded neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I understand that was possible in previous versions, and I also understand that version 4.0.0 is a total redesign towards a server-first approach, but nowhere in the documentation it is said whether embedded mode is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4.0.0.RELEASE is server only. Embedded support will be available in a future release.

Comment: Good to know! May I ask the estimated time of release?

Comment: Sorry, we've just released 4.0 GA and we don't have that info available yet about the scope of the next release.